# How to change screen and setState at the same time on first click in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, npm, stack-navigator

I have a function that changes the screen and sets the state at the same time that works given below (initial state of weapon is null):

```
var { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
  clickM16 = () => {
      this.setState({
        weapon: "M16"
      });

      navigate("Second", {weapon: this.state.weapon});

  }
```

And I am calling this on my second screen via {this.props.navigation.state.weapon}, but the state doesn't seem to update to M16 until I go back and click the button again.

I have console logged both above and below the setState function and on the first click it always gives me null but M16 when I go back and click it again.

Can I not run setState at the same time as navigating between screens? If I can what am I doing wrong.

TLDR: I'm trying to set state and change page in same function so I can then display the new state on the new page as text. The state change doesn't happen until the second click of the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting a small timeout for the navigate. The state change may not be complete when you hit the navigate instruction

```
var { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
 clickM16 = () => {
  this.setState({
    weapon: "M16"
  });

  setTimeout(() => navigate("Second", {weapon: this.state.weapon}),20);

}
```

Comment: Even better, setState takes a callback as a second argument, which is called after state was set, that's more elegant and safe than a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

`State` is supposed to be used as a helper to handle a small amount of data inside your component. The state life cycle ends as the component it belongs completely unmount. Also, note that `setState` is an asynchronous function, so you must not rely on React to handle sync situations for you. Updating your state will also make your component rerender, so you should use it carefully to avoid loss memory unnecessarily.

If you just want to pass data from a component to another, in this case using navigation props is enough, like this `navigate("Second", {weapon: 'M16'});`. You don't need to update your state to then be able to pass this data further. In fact, it makes no sense to update your state before navigation, since the current state itself will be lost in the next screen.

If you need to share the exact same state prop between more components, which doesn't seem to be the case, maybe you should consider using another approach, like Redux (https://redux.js.org/).

I recommend you to read the official docs for more detailed info:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Hope it helps

Edit:
Based on the information you provided below, if `weapon` will be an array, for example, and you need to push a new value to it before navigation, you should not use `setState`, try this instead:

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
clickM16 = () => {
  const { weapon } = this.state;
  weapon.push('M16');

  navigate("Second", { weapon });

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I have to update it as there are multiple weapons which will then be rendered on the second screen based on the state which will change based on which weapon they click. Thanks for trying and I don't know redux but I will read up on it. My question has been answered.

Comment: I think this still an antipattern solution. If you need to modify any data that you already have in your state to then pass this prop further, you also don't need to use ```setState```. You could access the required prop, update it as a variable and then pass it further. As I mentioned, every ```setState``` will trigger the ```render``` method again. By using timeout you are not only delaying the user experience, but also consuming unnecessary resources of your application

Comment: Also, by the code you provided, you are assigning the prop ```weapon``` with only a string value, so your next screen relies on the value itself, not the state. I suggest you take a look at the links I mentioned. Hope it helps

Comment: I haven’t deployed the API yet the string was just to test. But yeah maybe redux would be helpful.

Comment: I edited the answer with another approach. Setting state before navigation is not a good pattern. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I will give another suggestion:

```
var { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
  clickM16 = () => {
      this.setState({
        weapon: "M16"
      });
let sendPara = this.state.weapon
      navigate("Second", {weapon: sendPara});

  }
```

Recive parameter in respective component.

```
catName={this.props.navigation.state.params.sendPara}
```

I hope this may help you.